# C# StreamWriter, FileStream write

Tags: filestream, streamwriter, huffman-code

I'm working on Huffman algorithm right now and I need to write into output file some information (in order to decode what I've got): dictionary (character and its code), number of added zeros (count) and byte array. I tried to do something like this:

```
public void WriteInFile()
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("lab1output.txt"))
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, string> pair in Coded)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(pair);
        }
        sw.WriteLine(count);
    }
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("lab1output.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] input = bytedList.ToArray();
        fs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
    }
}
```

For example, I wrote 'hello' in my file. In the output file I expect to get this:

[h, 01]

[e, 000]

[l, 1]

[o, 001]

6  (number of added zeros)

F@ (encoded string)

**But I get this:**

F@, 01]

[e, 000]

[l, 1]

[o, 001]

6

Please tell me what's wrong and how I can fix this. Thanks!

**Edit:**
This is my Dictionary.

```
public Dictionary<char, string> Coded = new Dictionary<char, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < infoFromFile.Length; i++)
    {
        encodedSymbol = this.Root.Traverse(infoFromFile[i], new List<bool>()); // Traverse the tree
        if (!Coded.ContainsKey(infoFromFile[i]))
        {
            Coded.Add(infoFromFile[i], null);
            foreach (var e in encodedSymbol)
            {
                Coded[infoFromFile[i]] += ((e ? 1 : 0) + "");
            }
        }
        encodedMessage.AddRange(encodedSymbol);
    }
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered, so that would explain why your output is out of order. I think there is an `OrderedDictionary` you can swap in, though. To explain any other problems, we would probably need to see the code that adds items to your dictionary.

Comment: @Noah thank you. I added code that adds items to Dictionary